# javascript invalid quantifier breaks my jQuery in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to select, Highlight & convert the matching string into a link. So far it works find in jsFiddle.

But same script breaks when i try to use it in asp.net web forms i get following error

```
SyntaxError: invalid quantifier
[Break On This Error]   

var pattern = new RegExp("("+this+")", ["gi"]);
```

**Actual Code**

```
function HighlightKeywords(keywords)
{        
var el = $("#article-detail-desc");
$(keywords).each(function()
{
    var pattern = new RegExp("("+this+")", ["gi"]);
    var rs = "<a href='search.aspx?search=$1'<span style='background-color:#FFFF00;font-weight: bold;background-color:#FFFF00;'>$1</span></a>";
    el.html(el.html().replace(pattern, rs));
});
}       

HighlightKeywords(["got", "the","keywords", " tags " ]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LE3sg/6/

i am not sure why i keep getting this error in asp.net webform page

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? The issue seems to be with the `this` value. Use the "break on error" feature of the browser's dev tools and inspect that value.

Comment: I was able to fix the error in my actual code, It was due to syntax error when passing value to array from c# to JS i was wrapping whole array in `""` which was wrong. i missed it on debugging..  Array with double quote `""got", "the","keywords", " tags ""`

Answer (score 1):

When looping an array with jQuery `each` should always use the arguments in callback to access the array element and use `$.each` method as opposed to `$(selector).each`

```
$.each(keyowrds, function(index, item)
{
    var pattern = new RegExp("("+item+")", ["gi"]);
```

In code you are using if you log `typeof this` to console will find it is not actually a string

API reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/